# Как правильно распарсить json?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток. ) Есть JSON:

```
{"post1":{"name":"Hello!","rating":1,"img":"/p1.jpg"},"post2":{"name":"Launch new service","rating":1,"img":"/p2.jpg"}}
```

Как можно распарсить json так, чтобы post1 был в одном div, post2 - в другом и т.д., т.е. что-то похожее на:

```
<div id="post1"><p id="name">Hello!</p><p id="rating">1</p><img src="/p1.jpg"></div> 
<div id="post2"><p id="name">Launch new service</p><p id="rating">1</p><img src="/p2.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С jQuery используйте [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

Имея объект, легко вручную создать нужный DOM.